# Advice on this loop that prints decimal numbers into binary

Tags: c, loops, binary

so i'm having some issues with my loop. I'm trying to turn a decimal into it's binary representation, but the loop just iterates one time. any tips? (i'm new to C btw). thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{   
    int a,x;

    scanf("%i ", &a);

    if((a>0))            
    {
        x=a/2; 
        x=x*2;
        if ((x!=a))      
        {
            printf("1"); 
            a=(a-.5)/2;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("0");
            a=a/2;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which part of your code or problem is "decimal"?

Comment: the decimal would be the whatever number i get from scanf

Comment: Did you try debugging your code in an actual debugger?

Comment: If that is running on a **binary** digital computer, you will not get a "decimal", but a ... binary.

Comment: @CarlosM.Navarro `scanf("i",...` doesn't require the input to be in decimal. The number you get is just a number.

Comment: Your program looks like it could use some modulo (`%`).

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you don't have a loop.  An `if` checks a condition once and performs some action.  If you use `while`, that runs continuously until the condition is false.  So you need to change this:

```
if((a>0)) {
```

To this

```
while(a > 0) {
```

Also, get rid of the space in your `scanf` format:

```
scanf("%i", &a);
```

Otherwise it won't complete when you press Enter.

Comment: If `a == 0`, nothing is printed with `while(a > 0) {` .  `do {...} while (a)` fixes that.  Negative numbers are another issue.